# Struts2: action getting executed more than once incrementally

Tags: java, android, tomcat, struts2

I am using using **Struts 2.3.16 with Tomcat 7.0.47** to handle requests on a machine. The requests are being sent by an **Android application** in the following manner :-

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(0, false));
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://--my server IP--:port/webAppName/struts-action-name");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(Data_To_Be_Sent));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

However, on the server side, I am noticing that the action class is getting executed more and more times incrementally. For example, after deploying the webapp on tomcat, for the first request sent by my Android app, the struts' action class gets executed one time (as it should). **For the second request, the action class gets executed two times, and for the third request, it gets executed three times, and so on...**

Here is the **struts' action class** that I wrote:-

```
public class GetTagsAction extends ActionSupport {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private KrozonaLogger logger = new KrozonaLogger(this.getClass());
public String magazineName;
public InputStream inputStream;
public String xmlStream;
public byte[] incomingImageByte;
public String image;


public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
    toImageByte();
}

public String getMagazineName() {
    return magazineName;
}

public void setMagazineName(String magazineName) {
    this.magazineName = magazineName;
    logger.log("Magazine Name is: " + this.magazineName);
}

public byte[] getIncomingImageByte() {
    return incomingImageByte;
}

public void toImageByte() {
    this.incomingImageByte = Base64.decodeBase64(image);
    logger.log("Number of elements in incomingImage byte array: " + incomingImageByte.length);
}

public String getXmlStream() {
    return xmlStream;
}

public String execute() {
    try {
        this.xmlStream = DBAccessService.getXml(magazineName, incomingImageByte);
        if (xmlStream != null) {
            this.inputStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(xmlStream);
            return "success";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "failure";
}

public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}
}
```

**Here's the log that reveals the weird behaviour:-**

```
<---- for first request ----->
INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Number of elements in incomingImage byte array: 71739
INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Magazine Name is: Maxim
INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.service.DbService: Couldn't find a match for the input image


<---- for second request ----->
INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Number of elements in incomingImage byte array: 71458
INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Number of elements in incomingImage byte array: 71458
INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Magazine Name is: Maxim
INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Magazine Name is: Maxim
INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.service.DbService: Couldn't find a match for the input image
INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.service.DbService: Couldn't find a match for the input image


 <---- for third request ----->
 INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Number of elements in incomingImage byte array: 64528
 INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Number of elements in incomingImage byte array: 64528
 INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Number of elements in incomingImage byte array: 64528
 INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Magazine Name is: Maxim
 INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Magazine Name is: Maxim
 INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction: Magazine Name is: Maxim
 INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.service.DbService: Couldn't find a match for the input image
 INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.service.DbService: Couldn't find a match for the input image
 INFO - class com.krozona.databaseaccess.service.DbService: Couldn't find a match for the input image
```

And here's the **struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd" >
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="Krozona" namespace="/" extends="struts-default" >

    <action name="GetTags" class="com.krozona.databaseaccess.gatewayService.GetTagsAction" method="execute">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">text/plain</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        </result>
        <result name="failure">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
  </action>

  </package>
</struts>
```

Why this weird behavior? And how to solve this?

Comment: May be your Data_To_Be_Sent gets on increasing - like you're adding to it, instead of replacing its previous value. Try output of Data_To_Be_Sent before the HTTP request

Comment: I checked, no problem with the data that is being sent to the server...

Comment: @k_programmer: Are you familiar with struts?

Comment: yeah somewhat. The logs reveal that the functions iterate over a range of data - so either the data is summing up in your android app, or in your java class. Dump the data in console at both ends and see if there is something different from what you expect.

Comment: As you can see, I am receiving data more than once after first request and also, the execute() method of my action is getting called more and more number of times with each request. There's nothing wrong with the data but the class that receives the data is doing that more than once. I think the problem is related to "context" in struts2 but can't pin-point exactly what it is.